# How to print value in blade from $lookup in laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, lookup

I have two collections in MongoDB I want to aggregation between them, it worked fine but I don't know how to print the value in the blade(view)  of levels that's come from other collection?

```
$allRanges = Range::raw(( function($collection) {  
    return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                'from' => 'Levels',
                'localField' => 'LevelId',
                'foreignField'=> '_id',
                'as' => 'levels'
            ]
        ], [
            '$match' =>[
                'PlanTypeId'=> '5daad2c12939b70f0b7ff052'
            ]
        ],
    ]);
})))->toarray();
```

output:

```
=> [
        [
            "_id" => "5daad809095e6f0c7e37fbf2",
            "PlanTypeId" => "5daad2c12939b70f0b7ff052",
            "LevelId" => "5dab14832d31e850ea1644b2",
            "Range" => "range1",
            "step" => 1,
            "part" => 10,
            "levels" => MongoDB\Model\BSONArray {#3149
                flag::STD_PROP_LIST: false,
                flag::ARRAY_AS_PROPS: false,
                iteratorClass: "ArrayIterator",
                storage: [
                MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument {#3146
                    flag::STD_PROP_LIST: false,
                    flag::ARRAY_AS_PROPS: true,
                    iteratorClass: "ArrayIterator",
                    storage: [
                        "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId {#3147
                            +"oid": "5dab14832d31e850ea1644b2",
                        },
                        "PlanTypeId" => "5daad2c12939b70f0b7ff052",
                        "Level" => "1",
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
```

I get the Range but how get for example levels->Level?

```
<tr>
    @foreach($allRanges as $d)

    <td>{{$d['Range']}}</td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Try `$d['Range']->levels['Level'];`

Comment: @MayankPandeyz It's not work